# nodejs how to avoid blocking requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

hi i wrote this simple nodejs server:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/otherget', (req,res) => {
    res.send('other get');
});
app.get('/get', async (req, res) => {
    let response;
    try{
        response = await func1();

    }catch(error){

    }
    res.send('response: ' + response);
});

const func1 = () => {
    let j = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<10000000000; i++){
        j++;
    }
    return j;
}

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('listen 4000'));
```

and where the server gets a request to the route '/get' he cant perform any more requests units he has done with that one.

how can i prevent this situation when my server will have a lot of requests doing a lot of things?

Comment: First: Avoid Premature Optimization. Don't assume you are going to have a performance problem until you do. It's very rare that an HTTP server needs to do a lot of blocking work to service a request. If you had real async code then the server would be serving another request while it waited for the async function to resolve.

Comment: thanks for the answer, what do you mean by real async code?

Comment: if instead of the "crazy loop" i had 10 requests to the db back and forth that will take 10 seconds total its still block other requests in that period of time right? @Quentin

Comment: I've never seen a database API for Node.js that blocked. You should read up on the event loop. It's a JS fundamental.

Comment: Please do not delete the body of your question simply writing "solved" -- it makes the post useless for anyone visiting it.  If you want to append this text, that is fine, or if you really feel you need to delete the post, you could.

Comment: Better yet, if you have a solution you came up with, you could post it as an answer for visitors to this page to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

every thread can get blocked by your "crazy loop".
try to learn about js's event loop to know which kind of work can block it (cpu intensive tasks).

the general solution to survive to this kind of cpu intensive tasks is to create more threads / processes :

- you can fork, then you will be able to have two loops of this kind.
- you can create workers
- or you can load balance between mutiple servers
- you can dcreate a queue to prevent having to much parrallel work
- use the yield keyword to stop execution at specific checkpoints
- etc

every solution has its pros and cons

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what if instead of the "crazy loop" i had 10 requests to the db back and forth that will take 10 seconds total its still block other requests in that period of time right?

Comment: database calls are io. and io the opposite of cpu intensive. you can serve lots of parrallel request / s with no problem without multi processes

Comment: for exemple mysql has a sleep function : SELECT SLEEP(5); create a route doing only this and see how many concurrent connection you can have (spoiler : a lot). dont forget to activate connection pooling, because if you use only one connection you will see a "blocking" behavior. althrough the nodejs server itself will not be blocked. only the sql is.